# SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 in ssl certificate

Tags: apache, openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

I've got the error **AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key)**

When I search, I need to use this command in openssl

**openssl rsa -in file1.key -out file2.key**

After that, I got another error.

**unable to load Private Key
140596:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:686:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY**

I'm beginner for SSL certificate installation. Could you please help to solve ? Thanks.

Comment: Any solution you got?

Comment: This should help: https://serverfault.com/questions/160768/stop-apache-from-asking-for-ssl-password-each-restart And this helped for me: https://www.ssl247.fr/kb/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting/apache/tn-5634-error-sslpassphrasedialog-not-supported-win32 It tells you to remove the passphrase from the key file and comment out `SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin` in your conf file. (This was not a security issue for me because it's on development server, but it may be an issue for you.)

Comment: in my case, I fix this error by: save 'private.key' without BOM